# Google Colab performance very low

Tags: tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory

I am using Google Colaboratory ultimately to learn machine learn. I'm using keras with tensorflow as backend, using my computer with the same code below each epoch have a duration of 14s. On colab using accelerator gpu each epoch have a duration of 14s.

I found on the web an code to show gpu memory, and results are:
GPU Free: 11GB
CPU Memory: 12GB

Tensowflow show `device(0): GPU`

My code is simple:

```
model = Sequential()
#convolution    
model.add( Conv2D(6, 2, input_shape=(28, 28, 1) ) )
model.add( Activation('relu') )

#polling
model.add( MaxPool2D(2) )

model.add( Flatten() )

model.add( Dense(10) )
model.add( Activation('softmax'))

model.compile(...)
model.fit(...)
```

- Colab using CPU: ~16s per epoch
- Colab using GPU: ~13s per epoch
- My pc (cpu): ~14s per epoch

The dataset has 60000 samples (MNIST).
Any solution for this slow performance?

Comment: Both take 14s ? Which is slower ?

Comment: My pc is a bit slower.

Comment: @MohanRadhakrishnan comparing cpu to gpu